# Swift Cannot use instance member within property initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I want to do something like this in a class, but Swift doesn't allows it:

```
 let minDelay = Float(0.05) //Like #define minDelay 0.05 in Objective-C

 private var delay = minDelay
```

I get an error "Cannot use instance member minDelay within property initializer". What is the best way to correct this without initializing delay var in init or something?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a static variable (which means there is a single instance that belongs to the type):

```
class MyClass {

    static let minDelay: Float = 0.05
    // You can write `Self.minDelay` starting in Swift 5.1
    private var delay = MyClass.minDelay 

}
```

There are a bunch of ways to approach this, but this is probably the closest to the `#define` you mentioned. You could also define `minDelay` outside of the class entirely, but I don't think that makes sense since it is only relevant to this class.

Comment: `Self.minDelay` on beta :)

Comment: @Sulthan ooh! Adding to answer

Comment: @Sulthan Why would you confuse the reader with Self instead of the static class type? Self should be used when the type matters, and since this is a static variable (not class) I don't see any reason to replace Self with the static type

Comment: @J.Doe No, there is no reason to refer to the type with its name. It's about removing redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

Swift's property initializers can't reference other properties.

```
struct S {
    let a = 0
    let b = a // ❌
}
```

> error: cannot use instance member `a` within property initializer; property initializers run before `self` is available

This is one approach to trying to prevent circular definitions like this:

```
struct S {
    let a = b
    let b = a //❓what would these values even be?
}
```

Some languages like Java take a more tolerant approach, by letting a member reference any members above it (i.e. on a line above it), forming a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of interconnected member definitions.

Swift takes a stricter approach, and bans it outright. To get around this, you can:

1. Move your `minDelay` variable to a different place.

   - Make it a static member
   - Make it a static member of a different type (e.g. a `FooConstants` case-less enum).
   - Move it to a global variable (don't do this)
2. Make it a `lazy var`, as you said
3. Set its value in an initializer, where the order of assignments is explicitly expressed.